# Pytorch nn.CrossEntropyLoss() only returns -0.0

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, cross-entropy

Running the following code snippet
`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(torch.Tensor([0]), torch.Tensor([1]))`
returns
`tensor(-0.)`
How can this be? Am I missing something fundamental about this problem?

I have a super simple Feed-Forward NN model:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class FeedForwardNeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, S1, S2, S3):
        super(FeedForwardNeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(S1, S2)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(S2, S3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        return x

def train(data, S1, S2, S3, weight_decay, loss_fn, learning_rate=0.01):
    model = FeedForwardNeuralNet(S1, S2, S3)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=weight_decay)

    #py torch data loader
    for input, target in data:
        optimizer.zero_grad() # clear gradients
        output = model(input) # forward pass
        loss = loss_fn(output, target) # calculate loss
        print(loss.item())
        loss.backward() # calculate gradients
        optimizer.step() # update weights
    return model
```

And the loss remains at zero.

My data is in the shape:

X: [float, float]
Y: {0 or 1}

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_rem, y_train, y_rem = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_rem, y_rem, test_size=0.5)

X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train).type(torch.FloatTensor)
X_val = torch.from_numpy(X_val).type(torch.FloatTensor)
X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test).type(torch.FloatTensor)

y_train = torch.from_numpy(np.array(list(map(lambda a: \[a\], y_train)))).type(torch.FloatTensor)
y_val = torch.from_numpy(np.array(list(map(lambda a: \[a\], y_val)))).type(torch.FloatTensor)
y_test = torch.from_numpy(np.array(list(map(lambda a: \[a\], y_test)))).type(torch.FloatTensor)

train_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
validation_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_val, y_val)
test_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

batch_size=1000
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(validation_data, batch_size=len(validation_data), shuffle=False) # use the entire val dataset in one batch
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=len(test_data), shuffle=False) # use the entire test dataset in one batch
```

I run train with the following parameters
`train(data=train_loader, S1=2, S2=S2, S3=1, weight_decay=0.1, loss_fn=nn.CrossEntropyLoss())`

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked at your code, so I am only responding to your question of why `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(torch.Tensor([0]), torch.Tensor([1]))` returns `tensor(-0.)`.

From [the documentation for torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) (note that *C* = number of classes, *N* = number of instances):

> [image]

Note that `target` can be interpreted differently depending on its shape relative to `input`. If `target.shape == input.shape`, then `target` is interpreted as having class *probabilities*.

I think this is what is happening in your case: `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(torch.Tensor([0]), torch.Tensor([1]))` is 0 because the `CrossEntropyLoss` function is taking `target` to mean "The probability of class 0 should be 1". Then, since `input` is interpreted as containing logits, it's easy to see why the output is 0: you are telling the loss function that you want to do "unary classification", and *any* value for `input` will result in a zero cost for the loss function.

Probably what you want to do instead is to hand the loss function class *labels*.

(BTW, beware using `torch.Tensor`, [as it actually means `torch.FloatTensor`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-between-torch-tensor-and-torch-tensor/30786/2), which you might not have wanted.)